# Android app working on AVD but not on the phone?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-imageview

I have created a simple app consisting of only three buttons (physics, mathematics, aboutus). Behind the physics and the mathematics button, I have inserted many images of the formulas. In the aboutus button there is nothing but text. When I run my app on the AVD 2.3.3 it works perfectly fine. But when I try to run it on various different android phones it starts but when I click on any of the physics or mathematics buttons, the app closes and it displays that 'unfortunately formulafinder has stopped' (where formulafinder is my app name). I am putting my code below:

1. My physics.xml file looks like this

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="140dp"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageView1"
           android:src="@drawable/one1" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView2"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="200dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageView2"
           android:src="@drawable/one2" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView3"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="140dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageView3"
           android:src="@drawable/one3" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView4"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="140dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageView4"
           android:src="@drawable/one4" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView5"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="180dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageView5"
           android:src="@drawable/one5" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView6"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="200dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageView6"
           android:src="@drawable/one6" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView7"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="180dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageView7"
           android:src="@drawable/one7" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView8"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="180dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView7"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageView8"
           android:src="@drawable/one8" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView9"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="300dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView8"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageView9"
           android:src="@drawable/one9" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView10"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="180dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView9"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageView10"
           android:src="@drawable/one10" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView11"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="180dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView10"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageView11"
           android:src="@drawable/one11" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView12"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="180dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView11"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageView12"
           android:src="@drawable/one12" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView13"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="180dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView12"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageView13"
           android:src="@drawable/one13" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. My maths.xml looks like this

   ```
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageViewm1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="350dp"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewm1"
           android:src="@drawable/math1" />

         <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageViewm2"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="290dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewm1"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewm2"
           android:src="@drawable/math2" />

          <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageViewm3"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="140dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewm2"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewm3"
           android:src="@drawable/math3" />

           <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageViewm4"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="300dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewm3"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewm4"
           android:src="@drawable/math4" />

            <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageViewm5"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="220dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewm4"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewm5"
           android:src="@drawable/math5" />

             <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageViewm6"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="300dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewm5"
           android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewm6"
           android:src="@drawable/math6" />




   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
3. My activity_main.xml looks like this

   ```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="@string/button_physics_text" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="@string/button_maths_text" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button3"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="@string/about_us" />
   ```
4. My android_manifest.xml looks like this:

   ```
   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcherfinal"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name="com.example.test2.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name="com.example.test2.Physics"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_sub" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name="com.example.test2.Maths"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_maths" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name="com.example.test2.Aboutus"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_aboutus" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
   ```

One more thing I forgot to mention was that, when I was adding my images, it gave me an error something like 'unhandled event loop exception' and 'head size exceeds'. Sorry for not mentioning it earlier

Comment: You have launcher assigned to multiple activities. Only provide it to the one you want to launch first. See the answer below.

Comment: There are no multiple launchers defined in the manifest. Posting the logcat would be helpful to look in to the issue.

Comment: I cannot add the logcat file. It says character size is limited to 30000. When I add logcat it exceeds the limit

Comment: Paste the logcat as much as can fit

Answer (score 1):

Change your manifest file-

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcherfinal"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test2.Physics"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sub" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test2.Maths"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maths" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test2.Aboutus"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_aboutus" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I tried this one but it did not help, the same problem